# WSO2 ESB TargetHandler I/O error: General SSLEngine problem javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem

Tags: ssl, wso2

I am getting

```
Target Handler I/O error: General SSLEngine problem 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem and 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem, dbConnection = 
1" issue on WSO2 ESB proxy-services, while using HTTPS:// api url.
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the certificate.

If you are using a laodbalancer or reverse proxy on the front, you must include the certificate in the keystores of the WSO2 product you are using.

https://medium.com/@tharika/how-to-import-the-public-certificate-of-one-wso2-product-to-the-trust-store-of-another-d20b2b534cce

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get more information regarding the SSL connection issue you can enable the SSL debug logs. You can follow the blog post [1] to enable debug logs in the server.

[1]-https://medium.com/@dilsimchandrasena/how-to-enable-ssl-debug-logs-for-wso2-products-6de7276ffe10